# React native, main file is in wrong extension

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a react project with this command `npx react-native init projectName`,
It does create the project, however `App.js` have typeScript code in it, it compiles just fine but VScode keeps throwing an error about annotations being a part of `.ts` file only.
IK typescript, so if react does create typeScript code then why is the extension `.js`.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
One more thing I'd like to add, If I manually change `App.js` to `App.tsx` the error does go away and it still works fine, but I don't think that's the right way to go, and I don't intend to turn off javaScript checking is `vs Code`

Answer (score 0):

It's not typescript, but flow. More info: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29123

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, what you are seeing in `App.js` is not TypeScript code. It is [Flow](https://flow.org/), facebook's own static type checker for JavaScript.

If you want to use TypeScript then create project using this template:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

You can find more details about TypeScript integration in React Native here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript